# Get html element's content by id/class - Android

Tags: java, android, html, dom

I am trying to get the values of some specific elements from a html(whole web page) that is saved in a string, by ID or the class.

example HTML:

```
...
<h1 class="exampl-h1">Offer for Darko</h1>
...
```

From this i need the `Offer for Darko` part saved in a string.
Can someone help me how can I achieve in simple and effective way.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use String functions to find "exampl-h1">", the next "<", and then the substring between them.

Your assignment is to look-up the String functions and figure out how.